# Search in Messages or Files with Telegram API BOT

Tags: telegram-bot

ive added a Bot to my channel and make it admin
now my question is how can i make this bot to search in messages and forward it to a person with api
i tried to get messages with GetUpdate method but it only shows new messages is there any method to get all messages from the beginning

Answer (score 1):

Bot doesn't have on-demand access to messages, and as you mentioned, it just receives new messages as updates.

Accomplishing your desired task can be achieved by utilizing telegram core APIs instead of bot APIs.(There are gethistory and searchmessages APIs to do so)

Comment: can you please help me with them, like give me a example , it seems these method doesn't work like others

Comment: please take a look at Telethon documentation on Github( or any other implementation of Telegram Core APIs, in case if you're not comfortable with Python). unfortunately, we can't give you the complete solution in this site, but you can try to accomplish that yourself, and whenever you face a problem, you can ask here, and I/my friends are here to help you solve it.